# addClass not working after remove() jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I tables with drag and drop where I also have select checkbox and SelectAll checkbox.. But the problem is, when I select element and move it to the other table, I cannot select anymore that same item..

I think the problem is in part where I use `.remove()`.

You can see code on fidle link too.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("tbody.connectedSortable")

.sortable({

connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
delay: 150, //Needed to prevent accidental drag when trying to select
revert: 0,
helper: function (e, item) {

    console.log(e);

    //Basically, if you grab an unhighlighted item to drag, it will deselect (unhighlight) everything else
    if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
        item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //HERE'S HOW TO PASS THE SELECTED ITEMS TO THE `stop()` FUNCTION:

    //Clone the selected items into an array
    var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone(true);

    //Add a property to `item` called 'multidrag` that contains the
    //  selected items, then remove the selected items from the source list
    item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();

    //Now the selected items exist in memory, attached to the `item`,
    //  so we can access them later when we get to the `stop()` callback

    //Create the helper
    var helper = $('<tr/>');
    return helper.append(elements);
},
stop: function (e, ui) {
    //Now we access those items that we stored in `item`s data!

    var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');

    //`elements` now contains the originally selected items from the source list (the dragged items)!!

     $.each(elements,function(i,l){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    })



    //Finally I insert the selected items after the `item`, then remove the `item`, since
    //  item is a duplicate of one of the selected items.
    ui.item.after(elements).remove();

}

})



$('.selectall').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    if( $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').is(':checked')){
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody > tr').addClass('selected');
    }
    else{
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody > tr').removeClass('selected');
    }


});

$("tbody.connectedSortable input:checkbox").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
    } else{
        $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("selected");
        $selectall = $(this).closest('table').find('thead tr input:checkbox');
        $selectall.prop('checked',false)
    }
})
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/43j69/1/)

Comment: the thing is I think you attach events to some objects, but when you "move" those objects, you actually create a copy of it in another table and delete the original. But your copy doesn't have the event(s) attached, only the original object (which you deleted) does. So you should rather have a look at delegated event so that your put the event handler on the parent of your future "copied" objects.

Comment: I don't have so much experience with jQuery but I understand what is happening :/ I will try to figure out something, actually to try on some other way

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to helper function, in the helper function, you actually create a copy of the drag item and delete the original one. However, the copy one lose the event binding.

So, I just remove the helper function, and It works better, maybe this is the effect you want if I understand correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("tbody.connectedSortable")

.sortable({

connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
delay: 150, //Needed to prevent accidental drag when trying to select
revert: 0,
stop: function (e, ui) {
    //Now we access those items that we stored in `item`s data!

    var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');

    //`elements` now contains the originally selected items from the source list (the dragged items)!!

     $.each(elements,function(i,l){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    })



    //Finally I insert the selected items after the `item`, then remove the `item`, since
    //  item is a duplicate of one of the selected items.
    ui.item.after(elements).remove();

}

})
```

Here is the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/justinliang/43j69/2/)

Comment: I think I understand what you said, but the problem is now if you select all of them and try to move them or just 2 it will not work :/

Comment: so you want all of them can be draggable when you click select all?

Comment: Yes, to be draggable when chose one, when you select with check box of some of them or select all so you can move all of them..

Comment: That is good one, but if your tables are fixed.. Mine are not I am looping through foreach..So all of them have same clases, and I need to know which one I have selected!